# Laravel inserting data

Tags: database, laravel, insert

I have FotoController.php

and this is part of function:

```
$img = array(
    'name' => $filename,
    'gid' => $id,
);

$s = new Img($img);         
$create = $s->save();
```

My img model:

```
class Img extends Eloquent {

 public $timestamps = false;

 /**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $table = 'images';

 /**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 //protected $hidden = array('remember_token');

 protected $fillable = array('name', 'gid', 'views', 'likes');


}
```

But it doesn't add new record into the database.

Comment: You could just use the create method like so; `Img::create($img);`

Comment: could you show me in example?

Comment: Read the comment and youll find the example...

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new object and fill it at the same time this way, you need to use the fill method:

```
$img = array(
    'name' => $filename,
    'gid' => $id,
);

$s = new Img();
$s->fill($img);      
$s->save();
```

Or you can use the static create method on your model:

```
$img = array(
    'name' => $filename,
    'gid' => $id,
);

$s = Img::create($img);
```